# Execute Tasks in Periodic Times non blocked with Python

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, python-multithreading

I've already read a million posts about these questions, but i can't find any solution to my case.

I have a python process which read data from arduino serial port. These reads are execute inside a While true loop.

But every one second, i want to invite the read result to a database. Are many suggestions about Threading and timer.

But the data is read inside while loop, and i can't invite these data to a function in another thread. How can a make this?

Any example? Thanks a lot!  Bellow a sketch of my attempts

```
from threading import Timer

def send_db(data):
    #invite data to serial
    t = Timer(1,send_db,[data])
    t.start()

t = Timer(1,send_db,[data])
t.start()

while True:  #main function
    #read data from serial
    #how invite the data to another function?
```

Comment: Have the main thread read the data from the serial port and put it in a [`queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html), and have a second thread in a loop that gets any data in the `Queue` out, which it then stores it in the database. After that, have it `sleep()` for 1 second before allowing the loop to continue.

Comment: will the whole process run indefinitely?

Comment: In addition to the comment from @martineau you should ask yourself if the wait of 1s is needed when using a queue.

Comment: @Dalvenjia If you set the Thread to daemonic it will terminate with the main thread.

Comment: Anyone have a any example to solve this? The waiting for 1 second cannot be blocked, because my While loop continues receive store and process data.

Comment: I receive more than 1 data for second, but i not need store all datas in db, understand?